# HTML background fade color once

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to highlight a div with a text value to show users when a value in a cell has changed. I need the background to change color from red to white. I need it to do this once for values that have changed on page load and then remain white. What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you have a `div` whose color should be changed after page has been totally loaded.

1. So first thing to do it, you can set initial color to that `div`, so that when your page is loaded it will have `red` color
2. Next using JQuery code

   ```
   //This will change color of your div when everything has been totally loaded (text,images, etc.)

   window.onload = function(){ $('YOUR DIV').css('color',white);}
   ```

Hope it will help you

Comment: I need this to be conditional from code behind. I also need it to fade from one color to white. Basically, I need to alert the user a value in a cell has changed. Also, I have multiple divs "cells" which need to be white except when changed. All of the changes are handled during code behind so only elements that have changed (which I can track) will need to flash.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that

```js
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 $('#newContent').addClass('backgroundAnimated');
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
  50%  { background-color: #AD301B; }
  100% { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
  50%  { background-color: #AD301B; }
  100% { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
  50%  { background-color: #AD301B; }
  100% { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
}
@keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
  50%  { background-color: #AD301B; }
  100% { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
}

.backgroundAnimated{    
    background-image:none !important;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
       -moz-animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
         -o-animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
            animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>old value
<div id="newContent">New value</div>

<input type="button" value="test" />
```

Comment: The page post back is not cause by a button click. It can be various controls doing the postback. No single control will trigger this.